# Machine parsable list of html5 tags and attributes

Tags: html, w3c

I looked almost everywhere, but I simply cannot find any machine parsable html5 reference.

For html 4 / xhtml I could simply parse DTD, but for html5 there's no dtd. 
Is there ANY reference except for draft at http://dev.w3.org/html5/ ? (btw. html sructure of this draft is crap).

I need:

- list of tags
- list of arguments with types.
- list of required arguments

Comment: btw, here is the rationale for no "official" schema: http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/help-whatwg.org/2009-March/000192.html

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576415/is-there-a-machine-readable-version-of-html5-specs/

Answer (score 1):

Someone has been working on approximating the HTML5 spec in a DTD:  http://www.html5dtd.org/

It probably won't get you everything you want, but it may also be the closest you're going to find.  (Happy to be wrong on that one if someone knows of something better, of course!)

Comment: Looks like it's _work in progress_ :( Thanks for the lead though